# Gnome crashes on Shutter screencap and closing of VLC player

Tags: x11, gnome, nvidia, intel

I have a problem with my Fedora 24 installation:

On some specific UI Action, the gnome shell crashes. Two of the actions fail nearly every time: 
Closing the VLC player while it is playing a video and attemping to take a screen-selection with Shutter.

I am running Fedora on a notebook with the latest Intel graphic drivers provided by the distribution. The notebook has also an Nvidia graphics card and I was once running it on the proprietary Nvidia driver, but I uninstalled it because it hurt the battery too much. I think the driver might have left some garbage which causes the problems. (I uninstalled it via the official executable, though).

Here is a journalctl output just before such a crash: http://pastebin.ca/3720387

There are some errors, but I don't really know what they mean and Googling them does not give relevant information.

Answer (score 4):

After studying my problem for over an hour, I find a solution/workaround just a few minutes after a post to StackExchange ;)

The problem was the Gnome-Extension "TopIcons". I have been using it for a long time now, but it seems to be unstable with the current version of Gnome on my system. After deactivating it, everything works fine for now.